# code website in php with sef url's

Tags: php

How can I make the custom core php code website to show sef url. 
I mean to say how the coding technique should be altered in-order to make the site to have sef URL's.

I will elaborate...

suppose my php calls only the index.php file with some parameters to redirect to the page

```
/index.php?task=show_page2
```

I want this to make

```
/page2
```

Answer (score 1):

Use Apache's mod_rewrite module. It allows you to specify rules which map arbitrary request URIs to the real files and parameters you want to handle them.

For example, in a .htaccess file or Apache's httpd.conf:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule page2 index.php?task=show_page2 [L]
```

You do not have to change any of your PHP code as this happens at the web server level, before PHP is invoked.